# Read contents of a file containing key value pairs without normal parsing

Tags: java, apache-camel, mule, fuseesb, jbossfuse

My scenario is to read a file from a file endpoint which contains only key value paris like a property file and take a few data from it based on the key .

Any idea how to do them other that using a custom bean or java component.

I would like to know if this is possible any way in Mule or Camel.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [`Properties.load()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load(java.io.InputStream))? What have you tried so far, what problems are you running into, what have you tried to do to solve those problems, and how do your expected results differ from your actual results?

Comment: I feel this is a good question and does not deserve a -1 voting. Hence  +1 for changing that. Yes, he doesn't gave any code, but the question is clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a Camel route, to pickup files, then something like this

```
from("file:inbox")
   .convertBodyTo(Properties.class)
   .log("The foo value is {${body[foo]}")
   .log("The bar value is {${body[bar]}")
```

What we then need is a type converter from java.io.File -> java.util.Properties. Which we could add to camel-core out of the box.

I logged a ticket to add that type converter out of the box in Camel: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-7312

Comment: One more question to this . Can I use the same if the inbound endpoint is a Queue/topic ?

Comment: Properties can only load from File/InputStream/Reader, so you would need to do 2x convertyBodyTo, eg convertBodyTo(InputStream.class) and then to Properties.class

Comment: Thanks you Claus Ibsen

Comment: @ Claus: I converted as you said (for Queue scenario where i get string) 1.<convertBodyTo type="java.io.InputStream"> and 2. <convertBodyTo type="java.util.Properties">. The first gives a ByteArrayInputStream and  I am getting error like cannot convert from ByteArrayInputStream to Properties . Any idea?

Comment: Yeah you need to wait for next release of Camel, or build the type converter yourself

Comment: I thought it was there already and only now I got your answer. Thanks for your response I will work on a custom converter.

Answer (score 0):

I think to this problem explained, the very easy solution is to use java.util.Properties class. Load the file using Properties class which maintains key value pair only.