# Camel Processor And .cfg File

Tags: apache-camel

Does anybody know if there is a chance to read a .cfg file directly in a camel processor?

My .cfg looks like:
key=value
key=value
...

And I want to get a specific value after its key, but I want to do that in a processor!

Thank you!

Comment: You need to create the processor to use it. You can pass it in when you are instantiating the processor through the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use plain old Java:

```
 Reader reader = new FileReader("myprop.cfg");
 Properties prop = new Properties();
 prop.load(reader);
```

Also have a look at [Read contents of a file containing key value pairs without normal parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22523637/read-contents-of-a-file-containing-key-value-pairs-without-normal-parsing). As Claus Ibsen stated, there are good chances that a `File` -> `Properties` converter will be added in future Camel versions, see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-7312.

If you just need to access some key value pairs, use Camel's properties component:

```
<bean id="properties" class="org.apache.camel.component.properties.PropertiesComponent">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:com/mycompany/myprop.cfg"/>
</bean>
```

Access the property in your routes with the `{{key}}` syntax:

```
<to uri="{{cool.end}}"/>
```

The [Camel documentation](http://camel.apache.org/properties.html) shows all possibilities.